# Need macro to maintain font colour

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that prompts a user to select cells - these can be non adjacent - and paste them into a cell the user selects.
I found the macro somewhere online and it's great.

I am looking to add in font colour.
The cells being copied from are specific colours and I need to be able to maintain colour in the pasted cell.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
Sub G()

Dim strFinal$
Dim cell As Range
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngArea As Range
Dim rngTarget As Range

Set rngSource = Application.InputBox("Select cells to merge", Type:=8)
Set rngTarget = Application.InputBox("Select destination cell", Type:=8)
For Each rngArea In rngSource
    For Each cell In rngArea
        strFinal = strFinal & cell.Value & " "
    Next
Next
strFinal = Left$(strFinal, Len(strFinal) - 1)
rngTarget.Value = strFinal

End Sub
```

Edit: I have included an image showing what I am after - I have just done this manually to give a better description, but I am looking for a macro to do this with whichever cells the user selects. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Just the font color, or all of the cell's formatting?

Comment: Does the colour of the text vary within a cell or from cell to cell, or both?

Comment: If you do `Range1.Copy Destination:=Range2` it will copy over all values and formatting. If you dont want all formatting you'd have to loop through an copy the font data individually for each cell. Theres no easy way to copy and paste a Range's font, exclusive of other formats.

Comment: You mean each cell color should be preserved or do all cells have the same color in the source?

Answer (score 0):

This will copy the text from multiple cells into one cell, preserving the font color and size from each cell.

I've only used 2 non-contiguous cells in this example but it could easily be adapted to work with non-contiguous areas by adding a loop through `Areas`.

You could also add further code to copy over other types formatting, e.g. bold, italic etc, but I'm pretty sure that would need to be hard-coded.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyTextAndFont()
Dim cl As Range
Dim rngSrc As Range
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim chSrc As Characters
Dim chDst As Characters
Dim idxChr As Long
Dim cnt As Long

    Set rngSrc = Range("B2, B7")

    Set rngDst = Range("E5")
    
    rngDst.Value = ""
    
    For Each cl In rngSrc.Cells
        rngDst.Characters.Insert rngDst.Value & cl.Value
    Next cl
        
    For Each cl In rngSrc.Cells
        For idxChr = 1 To cl.Characters.Count
            cnt = cnt + 1
            Set chSrc = cl.Characters(idxChr, 1)
            Set chDst = rngDst.Characters(cnt, 1)
            chDst.Font.ColorIndex = chSrc.Font.ColorIndex
            chDst.Font.Size = chSrc.Font.Size
        Next idxChr
    Next cl
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your reply!  I managed to get it working. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.